# Emberjs auto update a view

Tags: ember.js

For my UI I need to display some information in my Application template for a navbar. I need to display the account name to be more precise.

When I load my page for the first time, my navbar is empty, but when I log in and after I make the transition, I would like to display those information on the nav bar.

The thing is that the information aren't un my localstorage yet when you are on the login page, but when you are on the Homepage my localstorage is populated but nothing changed in my view.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    username: fctToGetUserName()
})
```

Is there is any way to have a view updated every time you modify some data ?

[edit]

Is it possible to use an observes after my login to triggers an init method in my view like this ?

```
App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        login: function() {
            //DO MY LOGIN STUFF AND POPULATE MY LOCALSTORAGE AND CIE
            var isRegistered = true;
        }
    }
})

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    myVar: null,

    actions: {
        initMyVar: function() {
            myVar = localStorage["myVar"];
        }.observes('isRegistered')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would send an action to the controller to update the view. Something like this:

```
App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'],

    actions: {
        login: function() {
            var controller = this.get('controllers.application');
            controller.send('didLogin');
        }
    }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    myVar: null,

    actions: {
        didLogin: function() {
            this.set('myVar', localStorage['myVar']);
        }
    }
});

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    myVar: Ember.computed.alias('controller.myVar')
});
```